# Access to Canvas Items stack

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

As per [official documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm), all items inserted on the Tkinter `Canvas` are placed on a stack.

Though there are methods to raise, lower and remove items from the stack, could not find a method to access the stack.

Is there a way to access that stack ?

Or will I have to maintain my own stack for all items added to the canvas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` method will return all items based on whatever search criteria you give it. The items are returned in the stacking order. To get all item, use the search criteria `"all"`:

```
items = the_canvas.find("all")
```